# Can Visual Studio 2012 reverse engineer C++ code into UML diagrams?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, uml, reverse-engineering

When I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, I was pleased to discover the Architecture menu. I immediately jumped to the incorrect conclusion that I'd be able to ditch my less than satisfactory manual-creation UML software, and thus not have to keep wasting time keeping my code and UML in synch. I happily went away, starting on a new project, safe in the knowledge that I could put off the UML until later. I was disappointed therefore (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9665524/1227469)) to discover that whilst you CAN reverse engineer code to UML in VS2010, you can't do it with C++.

I'm wondering therefore if anyone can tell me whether Visual Studio 2012 adds this feature, as I cannot find any information on this topic - although I have read that VS2012 improves code generation from UML (i.e. the other way around).

Comment: Automatic creation of design documents from code is usually a very bad idea. It *might* be used as a starting point to create design docs but not anything beyond.

Comment: @icepack Can you explain why? I find it very useful as a tool to visualize my code.

Comment: From my experience it rarely matches your expectations and you have to do lots of work to make it useful. Simply because computers aren't smart enough yet. Design should be written be humans.

Comment: @icepack Perhaps, if you are looking at it from purely a design perspective. However, design isn't the only reason to use reverse engineered UML. It can be a great tool for quickly getting an overview of a large body of code without having to wade through (often poor) documentation or source code. You instantly get to see all the classes with their functions and data members, and how they all connect to each other. For my own work, I run four monitors, and I like to keep a UML diagram permenantly on one of them so whenever I want to I can glance up and instantly see my code layout.

Comment: I agree, for such purpose it can be helpful

Comment: I downloaded the VS2012 ultimate trial version last night, so if nobody else answers I will try it myself and post the answer.

Comment: @icepack "Automatic creation of design documents from code is usually a very bad idea." I couldn't disagree more.  Let's you visually scan the architecture of what you have and communicate it to others more clearly.  There is a reason the javadoc and doxygen have this built in.  

I used to do this with vizio and prior visual studio versions although I often had to tweak it because C++ doesnt have an interface/implement the way Java does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 1, and can confirm that it does not provide C++ support for UML reverse engineering.

Comment: I'm running Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 3 and features like "Architecture" --> "Generate Depenendecy Graph" work just fine for native C++ projects.

Comment: @BretKuhns Yes, but a dependency graph != a UML diagram.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't realize we were being literal with the use of `UML`.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405953/generating-uml-from-c-code) thread, although it does not strictly answer your question, might help you.